# How to create an Oauth 2.0 server which out put a client id and a client secret using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, owin

I want to create an Oauth 2.0 server tied to a sql database using OWIN where we can create applications and get client ids and client secrets for those applications. And access a simple resource using those ids and secrets.  (just like we get client id and client secret from google developer site by creating new application). If someone has a sample code or project It will be very help full. I've tried number of examples but still I couldn't find a way to create it. Thanks!

Comment: Please let us know first, what have you tried yet

Comment: tutorials like this. 

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/simple-oauth-server-implementing-a-simple-oauth-server-with-katana-oauth-authorization-server-components-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Rolling your own from scratch is **not** a simple undertaking.  I would recommend that you take a look at [IdentityServer3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3).  The principal contributors are Dominick Baier and Brock Allen.  They are the go-to guys for implementing OAuth 2 in .Net.  IdentityServer3 is very comprehensive and very flexible.

It runs as OWIN middleware and they have a number of samples that should help you get started.